Why "when we first begun" in Amazing Grace?
In the hymn Amazing Grace, the final verse reads thus:

When we've been there 10,000 years
Bright shining as the sun
We've no less days to sing God's praise
Than when we first begun

Given that we would typically say, "than when we first began", is "we... begun" simply written to achieve a rhyme with sun in line 2 or does it have some relationship to how English was in fact used at the time?

The following source has: “When we've been there ten thousand years,
bright shining as the sun,
we've no less days to sing God's praise,
than when we'd first begun.” https://www.hopepublishing.com/find-hymns-hw/hw3725.aspx

Stating the obvious: began doesn't rhyme with sun.

Also stating the obvious: syntactically correct when we first began is far more common than "invalid" when we first begun AND "valid / rhyming but verbose" when we'd first begun put together. As that linked usage chart shows, the syntactically invalid version seems to have reached a peak in the mid 1800s. But I can't really explain why it ever appeared or persisted. Half rhyme "there/years" is fine.

We'd've no fewer days.

The 1790 version of the hymn, where that line was first incorporated, also has "when we first begun."
This is likely just an unusual simple past form of the verb. The first (1888) edition of the OED mentions that "an alternative [past tense form of begin] from the old plural begun has also come down to the present day." A quick Ngram search suggests that this form used to be much more popular than it is now, which explains its appearance in a 1790 hymn.
Of course, in this case it was chosen in order to rhyme with "sun."

although this Ngram search indicates that "we begun" has never been more popular than "we began"

The following interesting analysis tries to collocate the usage of “begun” instead  of “began” amind different issues including non-standard  usages and poetic licences:

‘Begin – began – begun’ is a member of a small group of irregular verbs which change the vowel in the order i > a > u in the spelling and /ɪ/ > /æ/ > /ʌ/ in the pronunciation. The first issue is that in many non-standard forms of English, people use the past participle form in place of the past simple form: ‘I done it’.
The second issue is that even in standard English, it is very easy to
accidentally use the past participle form instead of the past simple
form, particularly with the ‘i/a/u’ group of irregular verbs. People
who would never say ‘I eaten it’ could easily say ‘I drunk it’
(particularly if they had, indeed, drank it).
John Newton, the slave trader turned Anglican priest and hymnwriter who wrote the words, was born in London, which, then as now, was a melting pot of varieties and accents of English, and there’s no way of knowing what his natural mode of English was.
Changing the last line to ‘began’ would, of course, spoil the rhyme. At least one source online tries to overcome this by writing ‘Than when we’d first begun’, which causes more problems than it solves.
In fact, many hymns include couplets which don’t rhyme when they are meant to. In some cases this is due to the the fact that the the pronunciation of one or both of the words has changed since the hymn was written, particularly with older hymns. At others, hymnwriters seem to have adopted a ‘near enough is good enough’ approach to rhyming.


except that Newton didn't write the final stanza as we now have it...
